# converting an std::map to an Rcpp::List?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

What would be the correct way of returning an `std::map< std::string, double >` as  an `Rcpp::List` object? The default `wrap()` method results in a named vector being returned to R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the future, include what you have tried in your question. It will be much more beneficial to you when others are able to explain *why* what you were trying was not working. Also, R `list`s (and `Rcpp::List`s) are much more versatile than `std::map`s, so I'm not quite sure how you are trying to store the map's data in the list. Presumably the map's keys correspond to the list's names; and the values to the list's values? Here's one way to do this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List map_to_list(Rcpp::CharacterVector cv, Rcpp::NumericVector nv) {
  std::map<std::string, double> my_map;

  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < cv.size(); i++) {
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(Rcpp::as<std::string>(cv[i]), nv[i]));
  }

  Rcpp::List my_list(my_map.size());
  Rcpp::CharacterVector list_names(my_map.size());
  std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator lhs = my_map.begin(), rhs = my_map.end();

  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; lhs != rhs; ++lhs, i++) {
    my_list[i] = lhs->second;
    list_names[i] = lhs->first;
  }

  my_list.attr("names") = list_names;
  return my_list;
}

/*** R

.names <- letters[1:20]
.values <- rnorm(20)

(res <- map_to_list(.names, .values))
#$a
#[1] -0.8596328

#$b
#[1] 0.1300086

#$c
#[1] -0.1439214

#$d
#[1] -1.017546

## etc...

*/
```

---

Starting with `Rcpp::List my_list(my_map.size());`, I'm initializing the return object to the size of the `std::map`; and likewise for an `Rcpp::CharacterVector` which will be used as the return object's names. Using a `map` iterator and an auxiliary index variable, the map's values (`iterator->second`) are assigned to the corresponding position in the list, whereas its keys (`iterator->first`) are assigned to the temporary name vector. Finally, assign this to the resulting list, and return it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to achieve (I was quietly hoping there was a more  'baked-in' method available)